# Find f ae-differentiable with $f´\in L^1(0,1)$ but not in $BV$...

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, bounded-variation

Here is a natural question which I didn't find in Measure Theory books:

Construct a continuous function $f(x)$ in $[0,1]$ with derivative at ae $x\in(0,1)$, and so that $f'(x)\in L^1(0,1)$, but such that $f$ is not of bounded variation.

The motivation would be the following: A well-known sufficient condition for absolute continuity asserts that

if $f$ is continuous, $f'(x)$ exists for all $x\in(0,1)$ except a countable set, and $f'(x)\in L^1(0,1)$, then $f$ is absolutely continuous (hence $f\in BV$).

In this theorem, "countable set" cannot be replaced by "null set", as the Cantor staircase shows. Is this also the case if we just want $f\in BV(0,1)$?

Some observations about temptative constructions:

(i) Cantor staicases alone would not work, since they are increasing, hence $BV$...

(ii) Volterra type constructions, which fill the complement of a Cantor set with
 blocks $x^a \sin(x^{-b})$ are not good either. For the derivatives of these blocks to be in $L^1$ one needs $a>b$, but then blocks are in $BV$, and probably also the resulting function...

Are there other natural examples to test with?

Comment: Take a up-down-stairs version of Cantor's staircase on each maximal open interval in the complement of Cantor's set with variation one. The resulting function is continuous, locally constant on the complement of Cantor set and has infinite variation on $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 3):

I just came out with a counterexample.

One produces a function similar to $x\sin(1/x)$ (which is not in $BV$),
but with the oscillating blocks made of Cantor staircases (hence continuous and with $f'(x)=0$ ae).

Here are the details:

Call $h(x)$ the usual Cantor staircase, ie $h:[0,1]\to[0,1]$, continuous, increasing, onto and with $h'(x)=0$ at almost every $x\in(0,1)$.

Next, dilate this function to  $h_n:[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n]\to [0,\frac1n]$
by
$$ h_n(x)= \frac1n h\Big(\frac{x-\frac1{n+1}}{\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}}\Big),\quad \mbox{if $n$ odd}$$
or 
$$ h_n(x)= \frac1n h\Big(1-\frac{x-\frac1{n+1}}{\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}}\Big),\quad \mbox{if $n$ even.}$$
Finally, define $f(x)=h_n(x)$ if $x\in [\frac1{n+1},\frac1n]$ and $f(0)=0$.

It is straightforward to verify that $f\in C[0,1]$ and $f'(x)=0$ a.e. $x\in(0,1)$.
Finally, $f\not\in BV[0,1]$ since 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\big|f(\frac1n)-f(\frac1{n+1})\big|=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{2n+1}\to\infty,\quad \mbox{as }N\to\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

Let $f$ be as in your assumptions, and let $0 = t_0, < t_1 < \dots < t_N = 1$ be given. Then for all $i\in \{1, \dots, N\}$, $f(t_{i} - f(t_{i-1}) = \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} f'(s) ds$. It follows that 
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^N |f(t_i) - f(t_{i-1})| = \sum_{i = 1}^N |\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} f'(s) ds| \le
\sum_{i = 1}^N \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} |f'(s)| ds = \int_0^1 |f'(s)| ds
$$
and therefore the function has bounded variation.

Comment: You can not assume fundamental theorem of calculus which you used unless $f$ is abosolutely continuous which in fact is $BV$

Comment: $f$ is absolutely continuous $\Longleftrightarrow f' \in L^1$. Look it up.

Comment: $f$ is absolutely continuous iff $f$ is differentiable a.e, $ f' \in L^1 $ and $ f(x) = f(a) + \int^x_a f'(t) dt $ for all $x$. These 3 assumptions are equivalent to absolute continuity. You can look it up in wiki or in any standard textbooks.

Comment: The phrasing is unfortunate. The statement $f' \in L^1$ can be taken to mean that, in the sense of distributions, your function $f$ has a derivative which is in $L^1$, in which case $f \in W^{1,1}$, which is contained in the space of functions of bounded variation. 

However, the question can be interpreted in another sense, which is that "if we take $f'$ to be the derivative of $f$ wherever it's defined and 0 elsewhere, that function is integrable." 

Hans has answered the question under the first interpretation, and user73815 seems to have answered it in the second.

Comment: @smiley - you're right.  I was thinking $f \in L^1$ in the sense of distributions, as Ray Yang explains in his comment. The original question however assumes merely that the derivative exists pointwise.